# Opening gif file using gallery(or similar) app programmatically

Tags: java, android, gif

In one of the activities in My application clicking a button saves a gif in a folder that shows up when I open my gallery app. How can I open the file immediately after saving using an intent or something similar??

This is how I'm saving:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File gifFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "GIF_"+ timeStamp + ".gif");
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
try{
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(gifFile);
    outStream.write(generateGIF());
    outStream.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this doesn't seem to work:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(gifFile);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri));
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What are your **specific** symptoms? Also, what is `mediaStorageDir`?

Comment: the answer below solved the problem. Thank you. But, mediaStorageDir is a File object that references the media storage directory. And it was giving me an error and breaking out of the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setDataAndType to pass the file URI and the type of the data :

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(gifFile);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri,"image/gif");
startActivity(intent);
```